# Stopping the jquery .on function turning to .off

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function

`$("#canvas").on("mousedown", handleMouseDown);`

but i dont know how the `.off` function part works i have used this

`$("#canvas").off("mousedown", handleMouseDown);`

but all that seems to do it stop all my other functions working instead of that one. Can any one help me with this function

```
 square.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Removed extra code

        $("#canvas").off("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
     context.fillStyle = color2;
        context.strokeStyle = color2;
        var putPoint2 = function (e) {
            if (dragging2) {
            var new_size = size/2;
                context.fillRect(e.offsetX-new_size, e.offsetY-new_size, size, size);
            }
        };
        engage2 = function (e) { // Made engage2() "global" to refer it in engage()
            dragging2 = true;
            putPoint2(e);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint2); // Repositioned event attachment
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage2); // Repositioned event attachment
        };
        var disengage2 = function () {
            dragging2 = false;
            context.beginPath();
            canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', putPoint2); // Added event detachment
            canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', disengage2); // Added event detachment
        };
        if (typeof engage === 'function') { // Added event detachment
            canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', engage);
        }
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage2);
    });
```

This function does not run properly with the .off event being used instead the line function still continues to run which is the bit that should be off

Comment: your off() syntax is correct

Comment: what other functions?

Comment: i know but thats why i was confused as to why it was not working

Comment: @ChristopherCraven how/when do you call off() function?

Comment: i just updated the question to show when im using it :D